# Bootstrap navbar not working on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use the below given code for my "home.html" using bootstrap.
But the search bar and everything on it is not getting displayed while browsing the site through mobile.
Please help with it!Thanks!

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Get Started</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="/search/" method="GET" id="search" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select what to search for" name="query" width="100px">
      <select name="drop" class="form-control" width="20">
      <option value="1"> Assigns</option>
      <option value="2"> Subjects(Tutorials)</option>
      <option value="3"> Subjects(Papers)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
  </form>


    </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> 

        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Please put the code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your toggle target doesn't match your collapse ID:

```
<button type="button"... data-target="#navigationbar">

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationbar">
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/12zvx3z2/)

Comment: Sorry! But while in mobile I click on the button through which all the buttons can be displayed, nothing gets changed after clicking on it.How to display it ?

Comment: It works just fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Make sure you're not clicking on the "Result" overlay that JSFiddle puts in the corner of the panel. (Click on the bottom edge of the menu button.)

Comment: Which JS files I have to include ??

Answer (score 2):

Your button which appears when the navbar is collapsed has its `data-target` pointing to an element id which does not exist (#navigationbar). Point it at the collapse element (#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1).

```
...
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
...
```

Live example: http://www.bootply.com/Xn2oJQYhih

Comment: Sorry! But while in mobile I click on the button through which all the buttons can be displayed, nothing gets changed after clicking on it.How
to display it ?

Comment: @JaineshPatel I'm not sure what you mean. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @JaineshPatel Have your tried the live example I have linked?

Comment: @JaineshPatel Hmm, I'm not sure. The live example is working for me and for others I asked to check it both in mobile and otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have all the libraries on your page the basic ones that you need for nav-collapse are bootstrap and jquery, you can add the next scripts to your head code

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/

For another verify the data-toggle has the right id related with your nav bar